# How to install iriunwebcam

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, software-installation, dpkg

I tried installing iriunwebcam on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

Used `sudo dpkg -i '<path>/iriunwebcam.deb'`.

It says

Errors were encountered while processing:
iriunwebcam

Then, used `sudo apt-get install -f`

Then it says,

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'v4l2loopback': Operation not permitted
dpkg: error processing package iriunwebcam (--configure):
 installed iriunwebcam package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 iriunwebcam
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

`sudo apt install '<path>/iriunwebcam.deb'` also produces the same error message.

Also tried `sudo apt --fix-broken install dpkg` and it says `dpkg is already the newest version (1.19.7ubuntu3).`

How can I correctly install iriunwebcam?

Comment: What happens when you install with `sudo apt install '<path>/iriunwebcam.deb'` ?

Also, try `sudo apt --fix-broken install iriunwebcam`

Comment: @Archisman Panigrahi it prompted me "Errors were encountered while processing: iriunwebcam " with "modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'v4l2loopback': Operation not permitted
dpkg: error processing package iriunwebcam (--install):
 installed iriunwebcam package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1"

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1297856/edit) the main question body to add that information.
Edit: I have edited your question to add this information

Comment: I suggest using `gdebi` instead of `dpkg` to install a package manually. Secondly, use `sudo apt --fix-broken install`  (without dpkg) to fix broken packages.

Comment: @Mansoor Ahmed Memon still the same.

Comment: @rusiruthushara This might help https://github.com/alievk/avatarify/issues/258. Try to purge `iriunwebcam`, then run `sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt clean` and install again using `sudo gdebi iriunwebcam.deb`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue. So, I will put the steps for someone who need. The following are the steps I did.

Step 1 : Iriun needs v4l2loopback-dkms as a dependency. First, uninstall the package and its dependencies if exits.

```
sudo apt purge v4l2loopback-dkms
```

Step 2 : Install required dependencies for Iriun.

```
sudo apt install qt5-default
sudo apt-get install v4l2loopback-dkms
```

This worked fine for me. Otherwise, Try the following.

```
git clone https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback.git
cd v4l2loopback
make
sudo su
make install
```

Step 3 : Reboot the system

```
reboot
```

If you have enabled secure boot in your machine, you have to confirm the password while allowing third party packages. So, probably you may do it while installing v4l2loopback-dkms. If that is the case make sure to enroll for mock and enter the same password while rebooting.

Step 4 : Install iriunwebcam (go to [iriun.com](https://iriun.com/) and download the deb)

```
sudo dpkg -i '<path>/iriunwebcam.deb'
```

That was all in my case.

However, if the step two doesn't work saying could not insert 4l2loopback, then try to install iriun without 4l2loopback-dkms dependency.

```
sudo dpkg -i --ignore-depends=4l2loopback-dkms '<path>/iriunwebcam.deb'
```

In this case you have to fix the dependency for iriunwebcam in `/var/lib/dpkg/status` as follwing (Remove 4l2loopback-dkms from `Depends:`)

```
Package: iriunwebcam
Status: install ok installed
Maintainer: Iriun
Architecture: all
Version: 2.4
Depends: qt5-default
Description: Iriun Webcam for Linux
```

Now, it should work fine for you :-)